Displayed math inside an ovalbox in the fancy box package
\begin{center}
\ovalbox{Consider the integral
$ I_n = \int_0^1$}
\end{center}

While using the fancybox package, the code above works as I would have expected, but the following gets me an error message about a missing $
\begin{center}
\ovalbox{Consider the integral
$$ I_n = \int_0^1$$}
\end{center}

How can I make this work?

$$ is not supported latex syntax, you would see the same with \mbox{$$ I_n = \int_0^1$$}  as you can not have display math in an hbox, the primitive $$ does not start display math it is interpreted as two $ so makes an empty inline math, and so the following I_n = \int_0^1 is in text mode.  Use
$\displaystyle I_n = \int_0^1$

Line breaks inside this ovalbox don't work. If you put something between double dollar signs, it doesn't appear on the same line as the words that precede it.

@MichaelHardy yes \ovalbox works like \fbox or \mbox it is a single line boc

Hope this will helps you:
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{empheq,fancybox}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Consider the integral
\begin{empheq}[box=\ovalbox]{align*}
I_n = \int_0^1
\end{empheq}
\end{center}

\end{document}


Note: I'm using the standard book class file, as you didn't mention anything, and also please avoid $$...$$, as already David mentioned
Edit
Is the one you expected?
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{empheq,fancybox}

\begin{document}

\ovalbox{
\begin{minipage}{10pc}
Consider the integral
\[
I_n = \int_0^1
\]
\end{minipage}
}

\end{document}


But I want the ovalbox to include a minipage that includes the words "Consider the integral" followed by the math display.

@MichaelHardy Please check the update and let me know

That seems to work. Except that it's not centered, but I think I can fix that.

Just add \begin{center} before \ovalbox and \end{center} after \end{minipage}} also if the suggestion meets your expectation, then click the tick mark
